# Organize storage of JSON array

Tags: storage, ipfs

I'm developing a Dapp based on Ethereum and I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to properly solve.

I need to store a very big JSON array composed by more or less 10k object where each object contains different fields such as floating numbers representing x and y coordinates of a polygon.

I can't find a way that I can use in order to store all these data in a decentralized way, I've read file system based technology such as IPFS and some decentralized databases such as BigChainDB.

My problem is that I need to associate each smart contract to one of these object and I need a way to navigate thought them. I wish to represent all the polygons contained in the different object on a map using a JS library but I can't understand how could I store these data and then query them in order to get the coordinates of the items that needs to be represented.

I've just started studying the technology, so I apologize in advance for any absurdities that maybe I've written. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a way to navigate through the JSON data within the smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Storing a data on IPFS is trivial using the CLI or any of their SDK libraries for the particular language you're using.

Once you upload content to your IPFS node you'll get back a content hash identifier (CID) which references the content you just uploaded.

The smart contract simply needs to store this CID in a global storage variable or in a mapping if you're going to have multiple.

Any clients can read the CID from the smart contract and use an IPFS client to fetch the data so long someone is still hosting it.